# Locations - problem with array/list as optional param

Tags: kotlin, ktor

Request A: `http://localhost:8080/api/organizations/1/scenarios?perProducts=1`,

Request B: `http://localhost:8080/api/organizations/1/scenarios?perProducts=1,2`

My Location class:

```
            @Location("/scenarios")
            data class Scenarios(
                val organization: Organization,
                val startValue: Int = 0,
                val perPage: Int = 10,
                val perProducts: List<Int> = listOf(),
                val byName: String = ""
            )
```

If I add one product id to path (request a) all is ok, but if I add two (request b) or more ids I get "bad request" in response. What do I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/organizations/1/scenarios?perProducts=1&perProducts=2
```

Locations under the hood uses [Data Convertion](https://ktor.io/docs/data-conversion.html) feature, and this is a way it handles multiple values.

Comment: Great! It should be documented.